# iOS - character encoding; NSLog prints differently in simulator than on device

Tags: ios, character-encoding

my little app prints a different NSLog output on the device (iPhone 4, 5.1) than on the 5.1-simulator.

The strings are coming from an external web service (in this case: Salesforce) and some contain German umlauts (ÄÖUäöü). The strings are NSLogged correctly on the simulator (Xcode 4.3.3, German Mac) but contain the usual strange mismatched characters when run on an iPhone 4 (in German language mode).
Screenshot: https://skitch.com/tschloss/efp6u/l-sim.txt-and-l-iph.txt-have-23-differences

I don't know where I can look for differences to eliminate this misbehaviour.

Comment: How are you encoding the strings received from the server? post code.

Comment: I am looking at the output displayed in the console inside of Xcode. So the iPhone out comes during a "tethered" build&run.

Comment: I mean, how are you encoding the NSData that you receive from the server?

Comment: I am using a 3rd party library for the communication with Salesforce. This library returns structures of objects, mostly NSSTring. But I did not change anything on the code between running in simulator and on the device. Shouldn't the same code do the same on both sides?

Comment: Nothing is guaranteed to be the same, that is _why_ you do the device testing.

Comment: ...but I can't imagine that this relatively primitive code _has_ to work such differently. So I assume there are some settings (probably runtime type of seetings) different. But I don't know where to look for possible locations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch your debugger, it may solved your encoding issue. 
To select which one to use, choose Edit Active Scheme from the Product menu and select the Run item in the left column. In the Info pane, choose the debugger you want to use from the Debugger pop-up menu. 
Take a look to the Apple [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html).

Comment: Thanksyou! But in both cases LLDB is already selected. Shall I switch to GDB and back to LLDB??